# How to repeat Middleman build process with different variables?

Tags: ruby, haml, middleman

We're using Middleman with HAML.

The site we're building should support multiple themes, and themes' markup differs from from one theme to another and we're using some variables to configure each theme.

I'm looking for a way to have Middleman to repeat the build for each theme I need with its variable values.

Comment: How exactly are you configuring the themes? Within config.rb? Or, in case of CSS, SASS variables? Can you give an example?

Comment: I've set a variable in haml and use it in the path to load different stylesheet. I wish to set this variable to different value for each design I want to create.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would recommend using a variable within `config.rb`, e.g.:

```
set :theme, ENV['THEME'] || 'red'
```

That way you can access it within your templates using `settings.theme`:

```
%p Current theme is #{content_tag(:strong, settings.theme)}.
```

Which should prompt: "Current theme is **red**."

---

Now the fun part, invoking ...

```
# on a linux/unix shell    
THEME='blue' middleman build
# on a windows shell
set THEME=red & middleman build
```

... or ...

```
# on a linux/unix shell    
THEME='yellow' middleman build
# on a windows shell
set THEME=yellow & middleman build
```

... via the shell sets `ENV['THEME']` e.g. your theme name and should bring you the different themed builds.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When trying to run in CMD (on Windows) the `THEME='blue'` I get the error: "'THEME' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Comment: I added the Windows shell/CMD versions, do these work for you?

Comment: I got error on Windows: `NoMethodError at /file.html
undefined method `theme' for #<Middleman::Application:0x21509400>

Ruby file.haml: in block in singletonclass, line 31
Web GET localhost/file.html`

Comment: How do you use the `settings.theme` variable within your template? Did you forget using `set :theme, ENV['THEME'] || 'red'` within your `config.rb`?

Comment: If I do `%p Current theme is #{content_tag(:strong, settings.theme)}.` it works. My use case is different because I want to do an `- if settings.theme?` logic which doesn't work even if I `set theme=true`. Can you help? I am not familiar with Ruby.

Comment: As this is probably another question:  can you open a new question here on stackoverflow with some concrete examples? (And vote this answer up to help others in the general solution worked for you)